# How can I organize my spiders into nested directories in Scrapy?

Tags: scrapy

I have the following directory structure:

```
my_project/
  __init__.py
  spiders/
    __init__.py
    my_spider.py
    other_spider.py
  pipeines.py
  # other files
```

Right now I can be in the `my_project` directory and start my crawl using `scrapy crawl my_spider`.

What I'd like to achieve is to be able to run `scrapy crawl my_spider` with this updated structure:

```
my_project/
  __init__.py
  spiders/
    __init__.py
    subtopic1/
      __init__.py # <-- I get the same error whether this is present or not
      my_spider.py
    subtopicx/
      other_spider.py
  pipeines.py
  # other files
```

But right now I get this error:

> KeyError: 'Spider not found: my_spider'

What is the appropriate way to organize Scrapy spiders into directories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to run this `scrapy crawl my_spider` from the dirctory which contains **scrapy.cfg**. You will not receive any error.

```
my_project/
  __init__.py
  spiders/
    __init__.py
     my_spider.py
     sub_directory
       __init__.py  
       other_spider.py
  pipeines.py
scrapy.cfg
```

Comment: What for other_spider? it didn't work for other_spider.

Comment: I do not think this answer is correct, see @pariola's answer.

Answer (score 16):

I know this is long over due but this is the right way to organize your spiders in nested directories. You set the modules location in the settings defined [here.](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#spider-modules)

Example:

```
SPIDER_MODULES = ['my_project.spiders', 'my_project.spiders.subtopic1', 'my_project.spiders.subtopicx']
```

Comment: This is an essential step if you are running your spiders with scrapyd, and have spiders in sub-directories. Thanks!

Comment: I am a beginner in Python and I was unable to apply your answer on the first attempt. After doing some tests, I found that it was necessary to create an empty file "__init__.py " in order for the folder to be recognized as a module. You might want to add this information in your answer so that it can be better understood by beginners, if you think that this is too basic to put, please ignore my comment.